# How to create a group of random numbers in C

Tags: c

So I'm trying to write a program that makes matrix from random numbers and user can input the number of lines and columns

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
  int c, x, n, m;

  printf("write the number of lines\n");
  scanf("%d", &n);

  for (c = 1; c <= n; c++) {
    x = rand() % 100 + 1;
    printf("%d\n", x);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

This is what I have, I need it to generate columns, but I don't know how. m would be the number of columns

Comment: use nested loops. The outer loop produces rows, the inner loop produces columns.

Comment: @Mangiux You can ask the user to specify the number of columns the same way as you ask the number of rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of many ways to do it

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int i, j, rows, columns;
    int **matrix;

    printf("write the number of rows\n");
    scanf("%d", &rows);
    printf("write the number of columns\n");
    scanf("%d", &columns);

    matrix = malloc(rows * sizeof *matrix);
    if (matrix == NULL)
        return -1;
    for (i = 0 ; i < rows ; i++)
    {
        matrix[i] = malloc(columns * sizeof(int));
        if (matrix[i] == NULL)
        {
            int k;

            for (k = i ; k >= 0 ; k--)
                free(matrix[k]);
            free(matrix);

            return -1;
        }

        for (j = 0 ; j < columns ; j++)
            matrix[i][j] = rand() % 100;
    }

    for (i = 0 ; i < rows ; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0 ; j < columns ; j++)
            printf("%5d", matrix[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }

    for (i = 0 ; i < rows ; i++)
    {
        if (matrix[i] == NULL)
            continue;
        free(matrix[i]);
    }
    free(matrix);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this code. I have another question, what do I have to do if I want the biggest number to be in right lower corner?

Comment: If you think this helped you, you can accept the answer, if you want to ask something else, ask another question. I don't understand what you mean _what do I have to do if I want the biggest number to be in right lower corner?_

Comment: May be you want to sort the numbers in some way?

Comment: Minor: consider this style of `malloc()` usage: `matrix = malloc(rows * sizeof *matrix);`.  Easy to code, check, maintain and no mis-matched type problems.

Comment: @chux You are right, many hard to detect bugs could arise from my code's style.